# How to find the index of a substring having two parts (with unknown number of white spaces) in a multi line string in Python

Tags: python

I have a multiple line string.

```
string="""
abc def ghi
jkl end vjk
mno pqr stu
"""
```

I want the index of the substring 'end vjk'.
The index can be found as `string.index('end vjk')`.
But the problem is that the second part of the substring is not known before hand (vjk can be replaced randomly by any other string).
Also the white spaces between the two parts may vary.

I tried  with the following code.

```
variable='vjk'
compare='end'(\s*) '%s' %variable
string.index(compare)
```

But the code in not working.
Can any body suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you just `.index("end")`?

Comment: No. The string is quite long and have multiple end strings. So finding the exact string "end vjk" is important

Comment: Use a regex. `r'end\s+{}'.format(variable)` https://regex101.com/r/r3eYZ4/1

Comment: do you want to allow other strings between `end` and `vjk` or just spaces and lines breaks? 
a good place to try regex is https://regexr.com

Comment: Only white spaces between end and vjk

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
variable='vjk'
compare='end %s' %variable
string.index(compare)
```

Comment: This works with fixed spacing between end and vjk. But if the spacing is changed then it do not work

Comment: or python3 style `variable='vjk'
compare="end {0}".format(variable)
string.index(compare)`

Comment: Use a regex in that case as said by @Harvey

Comment: Or, if possible, you could make your string into an easy to work with list: `[e for e in string.replace("\n"," ").split(" ") if e]` which you could join by a single space.

Answer (score 0):

regex can be used to solve this issue.

```
string="""
abc def ghi
jkl end vjk
mno pqr stu
"""   
var = 'vjk'
s = re.search("end\s+{}".format(var),string)
string.index(s.group()) # -> 17 in this case
```

A Regex object’s **search()** method searches the string it is passed for any matches to the regex. Match objects have a **group()** method that will return the actual matched text from the searched string.